# Git Pages: Sync Error after moving folders in/out of directory being tracked

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I've just recently learned some basics of GitHub and have been using gh-pages to host a website. I have been able to change/update the site successfully many times by adding/committing changes through the command line and then syncing the branch through my GH app.

But then I went and did something stupid. Git was tracking all files and folders inside my 'website' folder, which contained the index.html, styles folder, and an image. Since the initial website was just an experiment, I removed all of the files associated with it from the 'website' folder and onto the desktop and replaced them wholesale with my new, better files and folders inside the 'website' folder.

So, on git:

```
old site --> 'website folder'/index.html
             'webiste foler'/styles/main.css

new site --> 'website folder'/'root folder'/index.html
             'website folder'/'root folder'/styles/main.html
             'website folder'/'root folder'/about/about.html
             'website folder'/'root folder'/images/worker.jpg
```

My assumption was that, since GH would be tracking any changes inside the 'website folder,' that replacing what was inside it would be no big deal. However, since I added/committed/pushed all the changes from the command line (which worked, according to the 'git status' and 'git log' commands entered after the commit/push) I have been unable to sync the branch in the git app.

The 'sync' page in the app shows the old website items (index, main.css, and a photo) with a big DELETED message in red and checked boxes next to them. Below this, it says 'No unsynced commits'.

Here is the message I get when, from the branch page, I click 'Sync Branch':
"Sync Failed: Please commit all changes before syncing."

When I access the site url, it is still showing the old, crappy website.

Long explanation, I know, but I wanted to be precise.

Here is what I'm wondering:
a) what is causing the sync failure?

b) did replacing all the old files with new ones stored inside the root folder cause confusion? Meaning, does storing the new index.html inside the root folder mean that git doesn't know how to use the path that was working just fine with the old files? Would simply removing the files from the root folder change anything in terms of git knowing the correct path to the html?

c) Is there a way to push the new root folder to replace the old site that is being hosted at username.github.io/sitename ?

I spent tons of time working on the new files and would love to have them displayed (for myself and others) as a webpage accessible via a link instead of just loading and refreshing them as files through my own browser. Any insight or ideas to help me troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading all the way to the bottom!
-Jim

Answer (score 0):

old question, but people might find it through google when they're looking for what "Your page is having problems building: unable to sync pages directory" means.

To answer this question: You cannot move files somewhere else and have things still work, the gh-pages website always checked for index.html relative to the root. You can't move it to a different directory and still have gh-pages work, unless you then access the site as `username.github.io/projectname/newdir`. Any directory without an index.html is inaccessible to users.